# Equivalent of alarm(3600) in Python

Tags: python

Starting a Perl script with `alarm(3600)` will make the script abort if it is still running after one hour (3600 seconds).

Assume I want to set an upper bound on the running time of a Python script, what is the easiest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on Unix you could use [`signal.alarm`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.alarm).

Answer (score 2):

Just for your information: this is much self-descriptive to use multiplication when you set up  timers, for example `alarm(24 * 60 * 60)` for 24 hours, instead of `alarm(86400)` for the same period. Hope this will help keep your code clean and easy-maintainable :)

Comment: Good point! Tip: Your answer should probably be made as a comment instead of an answers, since you're commenting the question rather than providing an answer. Thanks anyway!